# fwrite printing garbage values like @@@@@

Tags: c, fwrite

```
double *array_out;
.......
FILE * pFile;
pFile = fopen ("Q1_n_iter.bin", "wb");
fwrite(array_out,sizeof(double),n*n,pFile);
fclose (pFile);
```

I have checked array_out is correctly populated, I am not able to figure out why it prints garbage instead of values in it.

Comment: This prints the binary representation of the data. Were you expecting numbers formatted for humans, or is the binary representation not what you expected? If the latter, how does it differ from what you expected?

Comment: How do you know it is printing garbage?  How are you examining the file?

Comment: Any specific reason to tag this as C++? Just curious

Comment: maybe you want to use `fprintf` instead of fwrite?

Comment: Did you actually allocate `n*n` elements to your array?  You don't show how `array_out` is initialized.

Comment: I expected it to print numbers like 100.0 100.0 ... ... which I can get through doing printf in code. I am checking the file Q1_n_iter.bin by opening it using vim.

Comment: Use `fprintf (...)` to write to a FILE stream using a formatting string.

Comment: Use formatted output, fprintf. `fwrite` is, well, not formatted printing, just raw data in machine dependent format.

Comment: You can try `fwrite(array_out,sizeof(double),n*n, stdout);` that gives you the same. Much like `fprintf` gives you the same format as `printf`

Comment: I am allowed to use only fwrite, I understand that values printed in file as @@@@@ are in machine dependent format. However I don't understand what is the use of that file. Also I want file Q1_n_iter.bin to be created as Q1_1000_10.bin. Here n and iter are command line arguments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The values `fwrite` writes into a file is not to be read directly with human eyes. You should let computer interpret them for you with `fread` or something. For example, you could do the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char * filename = "Q1_n_iter.bin";

int main( ) {
    double * array_out;
    double * array_in;
    FILE * pFile;

    array_out = malloc( 3 * sizeof * array_out );

    array_out[0] = 0.12;
    array_out[1] = 1.35;
    array_out[2] = 2.80;

    pFile = fopen( filename, "wb" );
    fwrite( array_out, sizeof * array_out, 3, pFile );
    fclose( pFile );
    free( array_out );

    array_in = malloc( 3 * sizeof * array_in );
    pFile = fopen( filename, "rb" );
    fread( array_in, sizeof * array_in, 3, pFile );

    for ( int i = 0; i < 3; i++ )
        printf( "%d: %.2f\n", i, array_in[i] );

    free( array_in );

    return 0;
}
```

And would receive the following output:

```
0: 0.12
1: 1.35
2: 2.80
```

If you want to print formatted data into the file, for a human to read, then you should rather use the function `fprintf`. It works just like the `printf`, with an additional field for specifying the output stream.

```
fprintf( FILE * stream, const char * FormatString, ... );
```

In your case, you should do it in the following manner:

```
// ...

for ( int i = 0; i < n * n; i++ )
    fprintf( pFile, "%.2f ", array_out[i] );

// ...
```

Remove `".2"` if you do not want rather 6 digits after the decimal point as default, specify another number if you want any other precision.

### Edit:

To create the file with the filename determined with command-line arguments, you could do the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char * filename;

int main( int argc, char * argv[] ) {

    // declarations
    // and what not

    filename = malloc( 256 );
    sprintf( filename, "Q1_%d_%d.bin", n, iter );

    // whatever
    free( filename );

    return 0;
}
```

Or, if you don't want to use the `sprintf`, include the `string.h` library and:

```
    // ...
    strcpy( filename, "Q1_" );
    strcat( filename, argv[1] );
    strcat( filename, "_" );
    strcat( filename, argv[2] );
    strcat( filename, ".bin" );
    // ...
```

Comment: I tried using fread for the same file it worked. now it makes sense to me. Also is there a way that I could use Q1_n_iter.bin to be created as Q1_1000_10.bin where n=1000,iter=10. They are command line arguments.

Comment: @Harshit I have edited the answer to include two different ways of doing what you've just asked in addition...